# Parameter incorrect issue with DateTime.ParseExtract

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the following line.
`DateTime.ParseExact("08-11-2013 07:38:05", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Nothing)`

It throws an error.

**Parameter is incorrect.**

***StackTrace***

> at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format,
>   DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)    at
>   System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider
>   provider)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format doesn't match that date you are providing, It should be:

```
"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

Considering you meanr November 8, 2013

You code should be:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("08-11-2013 07:38:05", 
                                  "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Instead of Nothing
```

You can also use `"d-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss"` format, since it will consider both single digit/double digit day and month.

**Also** it appears that you are coming from VB.Net back ground, where `Nothing` is default value, in C# you can use `null` for your case or better to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

For more see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You should add to your answer that his first attempt was trying to get the year (in 4 digits) then month (2 digits) and then days (2 digits), separated by "-" ... which he obviously didn't do as you pointed :)

Comment: @Noctis, your comment would be helpful for the OP, I also added Custom Date and Time Format link for more details.

Comment: true, your answer is correct, and probably will be the only thing read in the future :)